# Reportlab: How to set template for first page

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I need to set a template on my first page of the PDF file that is created using ReportLab. I have seen the flowable `NextPageTemplate` which is used to change the template on the next page. So anyone can help me to do this? For eg: I need to set a template such that the top of the page should be like below.

[image]

Please find my code below.

```
from reportlab.lib.colors import Color
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Frame, Paragraph, NextPageTemplate, PageBreak, PageTemplate


class NumberedCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._saved_page_states = []

    def showPage(self):
        self._saved_page_states.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()

    def save(self):
        """add page info to each page (page x of y)"""
        num_pages = len(self._saved_page_states)
        for state in self._saved_page_states:
            self.__dict__.update(state)
            self.draw_page_number(num_pages)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)

    def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
        self.setFont('Montserrat', 9)
        self.setLineWidth(0.1)
        self.setStrokeColor(Color(0, 0, 0, alpha=0.2))
        self.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 0, alpha=0.4))
        self.line(cm, 1.5 * cm, A4[0] - cm, 1.5 * cm)
        self.drawRightString(A4[0] - cm, 1.1 * cm, "Page %d of %d" % (self._pageNumber, page_count))


style = getSampleStyleSheet()['Normal']
style.fontName = 'Montserrat'
elements = []

doc = BaseDocTemplate('basedoc.pdf', showBoundary=1, pagesize=A4)
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Montserrat', 'Montserrat-Regular.ttf'))

frameT = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='normal')

frame1 = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width / 2 - 6, doc.height, id='col1')
frame2 = Frame(doc.leftMargin + doc.width / 2 + 6, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width / 2 - 6, doc.height, id='col2')

doc.addPageTemplates([
    PageTemplate(id='OneCol', frames=frameT),
    PageTemplate(id='TwoCol', frames=[frame1, frame2]),
])

elements.append(Paragraph("Frame one column, " * 500, style))
elements.append(NextPageTemplate('TwoCol'))
elements.append(PageBreak())
elements.append(Paragraph("Frame two columns,  " * 500, style))
elements.append(NextPageTemplate('OneCol'))
elements.append(PageBreak())
elements.append(Paragraph("Mohammed Shafeeque", style))

# start the construction of the pdf
doc.build(elements, canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas)
```